# Call constructor for struct class

Tags: c++, constructor

```
namespace CommunicatorApi
{
    class ApiObserver;

    class COMM_API_EXPORT Api
    {
        public:
            //! Basic constructor
            Api(ApiObserver& observer);
            //! Destructs the object and frees resources allocated by it
            ~Api();
    }
}
```

I am trying to call

```
#include <iostream>  
#include "include/communicator_api.h"  

using namespace std;  
int main()  
{  
    cout << "Hello, world, from Visual C++!" << endl;

    CommunicatorApi::Api::Api();

}
```

however i am recieveing the error

```
CommunicatorApi::Api::Api no approprate default constructor available
```

Comment: As the error is saying, you don't have a default constructor, so you can't default-construct an instance of the class.

Comment: The error message from the compiler is very clear. You don't have a default constructor for the class `Api` and yet you are trying to use it to construct an object.

Comment: Another question: what do you want to do? May be this:  CommunicatorApi::Api api();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no default constructor exists for class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981241/no-default-constructor-exists-for-class)

Comment: Please don't post code with `void main`, as it misleads people and means your code can't be just copied and pasted to try it out. `void main` has never been standard in either C or C++. FTFY this time.

Answer (score 2):

You already defined constructor with parameter so default constructor is not generated. [Conditions for automatic generation of default/copy/move ctor and copy/move assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-copy-move-ctor-and-copy-move-assi)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a custom defined constructor in the form of:

```
        Api(ApiObserver& observer);
```

you may not use the default constructor unless you explicitly define it too.

You can use one of the following methods to resolve the problem.

**Option 1: Define a default constructor**

```
class COMM_API_EXPORT Api
{
    public:
        //! Default constructor
        Api();
        //! Basic constructor
        Api(ApiObserver& observer);
        //! Destructs the object and frees resources allocated by it
        ~Api();
}
```

then, you can use:

```
CommunicatorApi::Api::Api();
```

**Option 2: Use the custom constructor**

```
CommunicatorApi::ApiObserver observer;
CommunicatorApi::Api::Api(observer);
```

**PS**

```
CommunicatorApi::Api::Api(observer);
```

creates a temporary object. You probably want to have an object that you can use later. For that, you need:

```
CommunicatorApi::Api apiObject(observer);
```

Comment: I suspect the temporary object is not what the OP is looking for.