# "No default constructor exists for class" even though I have a constructor?

Tags: c++

Apologies if this is below the community's paygrade. I only started learning about OOP and classes last night and English is not my native language.

I am trying to create a class called "Mammal" with its name, type of fur, number of legs and the presence of a tail as properties. This is what my mammal.h looks like.

```
//mammal.h
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Mammal
{
    public:
    //Properties
    enum Fur {bald, curly, frizzy, matted, shorthair, longhair, fluffy};
    Fur flooftype;
    int Legs;
    bool Tail;
    string Name;

    //Methods
    Mammal(string Name, Fur flooftype, int Legs, bool Tail);

    
    void identifyMammal(string Name, Fur flooftype, int Legs, bool Tail)
    {
        cout<<"Name: " << Name << endl;
        cout<<"Number of legs: "<< Legs << endl;
        cout<<"Fur type: "<< flooftype << endl;
        if(Tail==true){
            cout<<"This mammal has a tail.";            
        }else{
            cout<<"This mammal has no tail.";
        }
    }
};

Mammal::Mammal(string Name, Fur flooftype, int Legs, bool Tail)
{
    Name=Name;
    flooftype=flooftype;
    Legs=Legs;
    Tail=Tail;
}
```

And this is my main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "mammal.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mammal cat1;
    cout << Mammal.identifyMammal() << "." <<endl;
    cout << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am unable to get this code to compile, it gives me the following errors:

```
no default constructor exists for class "Mammal"
type name is not allowed
```

I'm not sure why it's not recognizing my constructor. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `Mammal cat1;` invokes default constructor, that is constructor taking no arguments. While your constructor requires 4 arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You've written a constructor, but your constructor isn't a *default* constructor. It takes the arguments `name`, `flooftype`, `Legs`, and `Tail`. To initialize a `Mammal` using that constructor, you'd write a call like

```
Mammal cat1("Captain", shorthair, 4, true);
```

C++ will automatically provide your class with a default constructor (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), the implicitly-declared and -defined default constructor sections), but *only if* you don't also write your own constructors. Because you wrote a non-default constructor, you no longer get the implicitly-declared default constructor, and so your class has no default constructor at all. Which means that a call that really needs to go to the default constructor

```
Mammal cat1;
```

Is a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

The line `Mammal cat1;` requires a default constructor because you are passing no arguments to it. Either write a default constructor or pass values for the four-parameter constructor you have written.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Mammal cat1;
```

This line calls default constructor, however you don`t have it because of:

```
Mammal::Mammal(string Name, Fur flooftype, int Legs, bool Tail)
```

Change to `Mammal cat1("name", matted, 2, true)`
or add `Mammal() = default`

Comment: But that would result in a 2-legged mammal :(

Comment: You're a two-legged mammal.

Answer (score 0):

You're constructor is `Mammal(string Name, Fur flooftype, int Legs, bool Tail);`
But you're trying to call the `Mammal()` constructor.

There's a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981241/no-default-constructor-exists-for-class).