# C++ re-enable the default c'tor?

Tags: c++, class

How may I re-enable the default c'tor if I wrote one of my own?

I know that writing a c'tor will disable the default one

Comment: Just write it again: `MyClass() : member1({}), member2({}) {}`

Comment: I would recommend initializing these members as part of the definition of even call another variant of the ctor

Comment: Assuming the class is named `MyClass`, in C++11 and later add `MyClass() = default` to the class definition.   Before C++11 (or if any bases or members don't have a default constructor) declare a constructor `MyClass()` and define it in a way that initialises all members and base classes to some chosen default value (e.g. using default constructor of every base or members, if there is one).

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4981241/589259). I'll leave it up to C++ devs here to see if it is a dupe or not.

Comment: @Aconcagua why do you suggest to do it that way instead of using `= default`?

Comment: @t.niese Old habits never die… Apart from, this assures correct initialisation of all members if there are primitive types involved – admitted, not fully equivalent to a real default constructor then. If not needed, the 'new' (cannot really say that after almost 10 years...) `= default` is just as fine, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might implement it as `default` (or with custom implementation if needed):

```
struct C
{
    explicit C(int) {} // Disable default constructor

    C() = default; // re-enable it :)
};
```