# How to solve compiler error: no matching function for call to 'dmhFS::dmhFS()' in my case?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, esp32

I write code for the ESP32 microcontroller.

I set up a class named "dmhWebServer".

This is the call to initiate my classes:

An object of the dmhFS class is created and I give it to the constructor of the dmhWebServer class by reference. For my error see the last code block that I posted. The other code block could explain the way to where the error shows up.

```
#include <dmhFS.h>
#include <dmhNetwork.h>
#include <dmhWebServer.h>

void setup()
{
    // initialize filesystems
    dmhFS fileSystem = dmhFS(SCK, MISO, MOSI, CS); // compiler is happy I have an object now

    // initialize Activate Busy Handshake
    dmhActivateBusy activateBusy = dmhActivateBusy();

    // initialize webserver
    dmhWebServer webServer(fileSystem, activateBusy); // compiler also happy (call by reference)
}
```

The class dmhFS has a custom constructor (header file, all good in here):

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LittleFS.h>
#include <dmhPinlist.h>

#ifndef DMHFS_H_
#define DMHFS_H_

class dmhFS
{
private:
  // serial peripheral interface
  SPIClass spi;
  String readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path);
  void writeFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, const char *message);
  void appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, const char *message);
  void listDir(fs::FS &fs, const char *dirname, uint8_t levels);

public:
  dmhFS(uint16_t sck, uint16_t miso, uint16_t mosi, uint16_t ss);
  void writeToSDCard();
  void saveData(std::string fileName, std::string contents);
  String readFileSDCard(std::string fileName);
};

#endif
```

Header file of the dmhWebServer class (not the whole thing):

```
public:
  dmhWebServer(dmhFS &fileSystem, dmhActivateBusy &activateBusyHandshake);
};
```

This is the dmhWebServer class:

```
class dmhWebServer
{
private:
// create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
  AsyncWebServer server = AsyncWebServer(80);
  // server to client communication
  AsyncEventSource events = AsyncEventSource("/events");
  void setupHandlers();
  void setupWebServer();
  void serveFiles();
  void setupStaticFilesHandlers();
  void setupEventHandler();
  void setupPostHandler();
  void onRequest(AsyncWebServerRequest *request);
  // http communication
  void sendToClient(const char *content, const char *jsEventName);
  void receiveFromClient(std::array<const char *, 2U> par);
  // uses SD Card
  dmhFS sharedFileSystem;
  // uses shared memory for data exchange with a activate busy handshake
  dmhActivateBusy abh;

public:
  dmhWebServer(dmhFS &fileSystem, dmhActivateBusy &activateBusyHandshake);
};
```

This is the constructor of the dmhWebServer class:

```
#include <dmhWebServer.h>
#include <dmhFS.h>
#include <dmhActivateBusy.h>
// This is the line where the compiler throws an error ,character 85 is ")"
dmhWebServer::dmhWebServer(dmhFS &fileSystem, dmhActivateBusy &activateBusyHandshake)
{
    // webserver sites handlers
    setupHandlers();

    abh = activateBusyHandshake;

    sharedFileSystem = fileSystem;

    // start web server, object "server" is instantiated as private member in header file
    server.begin();
}
```

My compiler says:

> src/dmhWebServer.cpp:5:85: error: no matching function for call to 'dmhFS::dmhFS()'

Line 5:85 is at the end of the constructor function declaration

This is my first question on StackOverflow since only lurking around here :) I try to clarify if something is not alright with the question.

I checked that I do the call by reference in C++ right. I am giving the constructor "dmhWebServer" what he wants.

What is the problem here?

Comment: I don't see the point of the local variables declared in `dmhWebServer::dmhWebServer` (or the ones in `setup`). You probably have member variables with the same names and need to read about using the initializer list. (The distinction between initialization and assignment is important in C++.)

Comment: I'm guessing your class `dmhWebServer` has a member of type `dmhFS`.  Since `dmhFS` doesn't have a default constructor you need to initialize that member explicitly in class `dmhWebServer`'s initializer list.

Comment: I'd say you're *abusing* references way too much. If you're not careful, they'll end up in some garbage memory at some point later (we don't see all your code so I am assuming you're using references all over) and you'll lose precious hours trying to debug for nothing.

Comment: @G.M. You guessed right. How would the implementation of a initializer list look in my class?

Comment: @molbdnilo I removed a duplicate declaration, because they are not local, the objects are private members of the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no default constructor exists for class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981241/no-default-constructor-exists-for-class)

Comment: What I found on initializer list was this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/ 
The correct syntax is shown with easy code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `dmhWebServer` constructor, you are not initializing the `abh` and `sharedFileSystem` members in the constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), so the compiler tries to [default-initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) those members, but the `dmhFS` class does not have a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), hence the error.

You need to use the member initialization list for members with non-default constructors, eg:

```
dmhWebServer::dmhWebServer(dmhFS &fileSystem, dmhActivateBusy &activateBusyHandshake)
    : sharedFileSystem(fileSystem), abh(activateBusyHandshake)
{
    setupHandlers();
    server.begin();
}
```